# Streetwise substituting Arcana, History and Religion?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, content-identification

I have recently run into a conundrum. Recently we have started playing DnD4e. While researching and building our PCs I stumbled upon a modifier that allowed me to substitute a Streetwise check for a check that would otherwise require Arcana, History or Religion, in a city where I'd previously passed a Streetwise check. I do not remember whether this was a feat, a background or whatever, and I may not be remembering it exactly right, but that was the overall gist of it.

My problem now is that I cannot find it again in order to assign it within the Character Builder. Can anyone help me with this? Is my mind just playing tricks on me making me remember something I'd read from a completely unrelated ruleset? What gives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are thinking of the Streetwise Utility power Secrets of the City. It is in Dragon Magazine 389.

It does everything you say, but also allows substituting for Intelligence checks as well.

Comment: Legend! It completely went over my head that I'd found it when prospecting for level-ups. Cheers!